# Algorithm for determining points from given dataset that are within a convex hull defined by a subset of original dataset

Tags: algorithms, vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Having a dataset of `x,y,z`  with `n` points like:

```
1.59855e+006 -185000 -3082.85  
1.59855e+006 -184700 -3064.05 
1.59855e+006 -184400 -3035.3 
1.59855e+006 -184100 -3011.24  
1.59855e+006 -183800 -2990.73  
1.59855e+006 -183500 -2970.26
1.59855e+006 -183200 -2948.27
1.59855e+006 -182900 -2932.94  
1.59855e+006 -182600 -2916.47 
1.59855e+006 -182300 -2897.31
1.59855e+006 -182000 -2881.39 
1.59855e+006 -181700 -2866.74  
1.59855e+006 -181400 -2887.98
1.59855e+006 -181100 -2935.13
1.59855e+006 -180800 -2957.79
1.59855e+006 -180500 -2946.47 
1.59855e+006 -180200 -2917.82 
1.59855e+006 -179900 -2905.03 
1.59855e+006 -179600 -2917.55 
1.59855e+006 -179300 -2896.38 
1.59855e+006 -179000 -2925.13
1.59855e+006 -178700 -2953.91 
1.59855e+006 -178400 -2956.31 
1.59855e+006 -178100 -2836.47
```

Supposing I have `8` or more points that represent a loop that lives in dataset domain

To solve it I was planning to set `z=0`, and deal only with `x,y` points, For instance, if I have 3 points inside a plane like in image (these 3 points are inside all dataset):

[image]

I would like to get the bounded subset of the plane, I mean all points that form blue shape (formed by a rubber band stretched). 
I have the plane and red points, these red points when connected form a convex loop.

something like getting all points inside blue contour:
[image]

What algorithm should I use to get all points that are inside that loop?
I mean loop is formed by 8 points of dataset (assuming is convex and points have some distance between them)

Kindly suggest some ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by a loop (in three dimensions)? Do you mean the convex hull of 8 or more points?

Comment: Suppose I connected 8 points forming a loop (8 points are taken from dataset), Is it possible to get points that are inside that loop, What can it be done?

Comment: I was planning to make it easier fixing all z in dataset to 0, so problem is now how to get points inside loop (x,y)

Comment: So do you know the eight points in advance, and want to find every point in your data set that is inside the convex hull of those eight points? Or you're trying to find the convex hull of your data set (with no additional points prescribed)? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You state that 8 or more points can form the loop -- would the loop not be the convex hull off all points in your dataset, and thus by definition contain all other points in your dataset (since they are in the convex hull)? Your problem would have a more interesting solution if we are only allowed to choose exactly 8 points.

Comment: I want to find every point in data set that is inside the convex hull of eight points (eight points are inside original dataset)?

Comment: Ok, I think I am beginning to understand. Given an arbitrary set of 8 points (from your dataset), we form the convex hull of those 8 points, then determine which other points from your dataset are within that convex hull?

Comment: @ErikMiehling well in fact the number of points would be n>=3 and n<= all points on dataset, I am interested on getting points inside this n points. The anwwer for last comment is Yes I would like to get all points inside that  convex hull

Comment: Ok, I see, I will put some thought into it.

Comment: @ErikMiehling I have tried to think on a solution, And best I could do is to fix all z in dataset to 0, so I would only need to get points inside convex hull in 2D...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am correctly understanding what you wish to solve. The general idea is as follows: first, construct a convex hull of a selection of $m$ points from your dataset of size $n\ge m$. There are many algorithms that can do this (of varying efficiency); I am making use of the gift-wrapping algorithm (basically verbatim from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm). Once the convex hull has been constructed, we form half-spaces from the pairs of neighboring points on the convex hull. Then, running through each point in the dataset, we can check if the point is within *all* half-spaces. If so, then that point is within our convex hull of selected points. I'm not making any guarantees about the efficiency of this algorithm, just providing something that (hopefully, have not tested it) works for now.

Let us denote $S$ by the set of $m$ selected points from our dataset.

```
// CONVEX HULL CODE
pointOnHull = leftmost point in S

i = 0
repeat
    P[i] = pointOnHull
    endpoint = S[0]         // initial endpoint for a candidate edge on the hull
    for j from 1 to m
        if (endpoint == pointOnHull) or (S[j] is on left of line from P[i] to endpoint)
            endpoint = S[j]   // found greater left turn, update endpoint
    end
    i = i+1
    pointOnHull = endpoint
until endpoint == P[0]      // wrapped around to first hull point
```

Given the points that make up the convex hull of $S$, we now construct the half-spaces that define the convex hull (note that each point P[i] is a pair; I use P[i].x to denote the x-coordinate). I have denoted the original dataset as D.

```
// HALF-SPACE CODE
m_hull = |P|  // number of points that make up the hull

for j from 1 to m_hull-1   // loop over line segments of hull to find inward-pointing normals, (dy,-dx)
     dx[j] = P[j+1].x - P[j].x
     dy[j] = P[j+1].y - P[j].y
end
dx[m_hull] = P[1].x - P[m_hull].x
dy[m_hull] = P[1].y - P[m_hull].y

for k from 1 to n          // checking all points in dataset
    for p from 1 to m_hull    // comparing to all half-spaces
       inHullHalfspace[k,p] = (dy[p]*(D[k].x - P[p].x) - dx[p]*(D[k].y - P[p].y) >= 0)   // logical operator, will return 1 if true, 0 otherwise
    end
    inHull[k] = prod[inHullHalfspace[k,:],2]   // logical 'and' across columns, will contain 1 if dataset element k is in the convex hull of selected m points
end
```

The vector inHull should be what you are after. This should not be too difficult to extend to the 3-dimensional case, but that's all from me tonight. The textbook title Convex Optimization by Boyd may be of help in studying the math behind the half-spaces if you are not familiar.

Comment: You are creating inHullHalfspace Matrix that will contain 1 if point P(x,y) is inside hull and 0 otherwise, Is this correct? 
Also could you please explain a little more the instruction `cumprod[inHullHalfspace[k,:],2]` ? knowing `inHullHalfspace` is a matrix, then cumprod(A,2) returns the cumulative product of each row. However you are taking k...But I got lost here

Comment: Yes, you are right. To answer your second question, i actually intended to just use prod, not cumprod. We want the vector inHull to consist of just zeros and ones. I've been thinking more about the generalization to three dimensions. I see two difficulties: first, we need a different algorithm to find the convex hull, then once we have the convex hull, it will be more difficult to define the inward pointing normal compared to the two dimensional case.

Comment: prod(argument,2) is the correct command to use, as we wish to take the product over columns. At least, this is how it works in Matlab. I suppose this could be done outside of the k loop by just removing the k indices as well.

Comment: What I understand is you are using `cumprod[inHullHalfspace[k,:],2]  ` as an AND to see if that coordinate is `1` for all points, however in a little test I am doing, I get a matrix composed almost by  zeros, and I know it should at least contain 5 columns equal to 1...

Comment: Is formula correct as I have tested all by hand, and not getting correct comparison in  `if (dy[p] * (D[k].X - P[p].X) - dx[p] * (D[k].Y - P[p].Y) >= 0)
                        inHullHalfspace[k, p] = 1;
                    else
                        inHullHalfspace[k, p] = 0;`

Comment: Yes, we are doing a logical AND to see if the given datapoint is within all half-spaces. What I mean by within a half-space is that the angle between the normal $(dy,-dx)$ and the vector $(D_x(k) - P_x(p),D_y(k) - P_y(p))$ is acute (where $(P_x(p),P_y(p))$ is a point on the line defining the half-space). It would be a useful exercise to check through the math to ensure everything is correct.

Comment: Also note that the order in which the vector of points of the convex hull, $P$, is constructed is crucial is obtaining the correct normal vector (that is, inward vs. outward) of each half-space.

Comment: I got lost a little when programing it, I am getting a inHullHalfspace matrix full of zeros, and already verified some angles...Where do you think could be the error?

Comment: I would start by looking at the points that make up your convex hull and comparing the normals of the half-spaces of the pairs of points on the hull to some hand-written calculations.

Comment: I have done `(378, 110)
(190, 130)
( 65, 365)
(300, 100)
(500, 425)
(225, 395)
(378, 110)` and gotten `dx          
[0] 125
[1] 110
[2] 78
[3] 122
[4] -275
[5] -160
[6] 125 

dy
[0] -235
[1] -30
[2] 10
[3] 315
[4] -30
[5] -30
[6] -235`

Comment: Plot the points in the order given, it is not convex, re-check the algorithm that constructs your convex hull. Also, we should move this discussion to chat if you have any more questions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13693/discussion-between-erik-miehling-and-cminor)

Comment: Thank you I have made some progress, I could not have done it with out your help, than you

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear. If I come up with something for the 3D case I'll add it to my answer above.